# I want to show table data using Ajax in Asp.Net MVC. What is wrong with this Ajax syntax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I want to show table data using Ajax request.

**Here is my Ajax Syntax:**

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
                var table = $("#attendance").DataTable({
                    ajax: {
                        url: '@Url.Action("GetAttendance", new {id = Model.Student.Id})',
                        dataSrc: ""
                    },
                    columns: [
                        {
                            data: "Date",
                            render: function(data) {
                                return data;
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            data: "Status.StudentStatus",
                            render: function(data) {
                                return data;
                            }

                        }
                    ]
                });
```

Here is my action method:

```
  public JsonResult GetAttendance(int id)
    {
        var studentAttendance = _context.Attendances.ToList().Where(m => m.StudentId == id);
        return Json(studentAttendance, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Now, where am I wrong?

Comment: It depends upon where you are using this code. If you have written this code in a separate .js file it will not work at all. other than that only browser's debug tools can help you here. You can start by inspecting the source code of your razor page (specifically script section)

Comment: @Alamzaib Farooq Can you please tell me if you tried any solution?

Comment: @kblau Yes, I have solved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please plug in the following example.  If you don't mind, please just follow my example, and then you will be able to fix your issue.

Controller/Model:

```
public class AjaxViewModel
{
    public string theDate { get; set; }
    public string StudentStatue { get; set; }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public string GetAttendance()
    {
        AjaxViewModel aViewModel = new AjaxViewModel { StudentStatue = "stat4", theDate = "12/24/2005" };
        AjaxViewModel aViewModel2 = new AjaxViewModel { StudentStatue = "stat5", theDate = "12/24/2005" };
        AjaxViewModel aViewModel3 = new AjaxViewModel { StudentStatue = "stat6", theDate = "12/24/2005" };

        IList<AjaxViewModel> data = new List<AjaxViewModel>();
        data.Add(aViewModel);
        data.Add(aViewModel2);
        data.Add(aViewModel3);

        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string json = js.Serialize(data);
        json = "{ \"data\": " + json;
        json = json + " }";
        return json;
    }
```

View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index2020</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/DataTables/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#uiDataTable").DataTable({
                "ajax": '@Url.Action("GetAttendance")',
                columns: [
                    {
                        "data": "theDate"
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "StudentStatue"
                    }
                ]
            });
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="uiDataTable" class="display table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Date
                </th>
                <th>
                    Status
                </th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```